# Problems with the existence of limits of several variables

Tags: calculus, limits, problem-solving

I started some time studying calculus of two variables, and I'm having difficulty in knowing (and prove) that a limit does not exist, how could I resolve, for example, these, whose statement asks to show that there are? $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^9y}{(x^6+y^2)^2}\\\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\\\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} \frac{x^3+yz^2}{x^4+y^2+z^2}\\\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^2y^2}{x^4+y^4}\\\lim_{(x,y,z)\to(0,0,0)} \frac{x^2+y^2-z^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}$$

Answer (score 2):

You need consider paths on the $xy$-plane as follows:

If a limit exists, then it must approach the same value no matter what way you approach $(0,0)$. Consider the first example. If you take a line $y=x$ and approach $(0,0)$ along that line, you get,

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^9y}{(x^6+y^2)^2} =  \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^{10}}{(x^6 + x^2)^2}$$

Does this limit exist? Now try with $y = x^3$.

Similarly for the second problem, consider the path $y = mx$, and you get

$$\lim_{(x,y)\rightarrow (0,0)} \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)} = \lim_{x\rightarrow 0} \frac{x^2}{x^2 + m^2x^2} = \frac{1}{1+m^2}$$

So the limit depends on $m$. Hence the limit cannot exist. Can you think of similar paths for the remaining examples?

Comment: That was a bit confusing for a beginner in this content.
Although these two examples, there are no limits when $y = x$ when $y = mx?$

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not understand your question. In such problems, where you want to show that the limit does not exist, you want to look at specific paths (in the xy-plane, etc) and see if the limit is the same in along all the paths. If it isn't the same, the multivariable limit does not exist. So in the first case, you look at the paths, y=x and y=x^3 and check that the limits are different. In the second case, you will get different values for your limit each depending on m. So again, the limit will not exist. I hope that helps, let me know if you need more clarification.

Answer (score 0):

1) What happens if we approach along $y=x$? What about if we approach along $y=x^3$?

2) For this one, there is a "universal" strategy: if we see $x^2+y^2$ at the bottom, then $x=r\cos\theta$, $y=r\sin\theta$ is almost always useful Simplify, we get $\cos^2\theta$. Thus what happens depends on the direction of approach, the limit does not exist.

3) If we set $y=z=0$, the thing blows up (in different directions) as $x\to 0$.

4) We get different limits if we approach along $y=x$ and if we approach along $y=2x$.

5) Set $z=0$ and see what happens. Set $x=0$ and $y=z$ and see what happens.