# How to prove a partial derivative is continuous using squeeze theorem?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, continuity, partial-derivative

I have a function, and I am trying to determine where its partial derivatives are continuous. The function is $h(x,y)=\frac{x^4-x^3}{x^2+y^2}$ when $(x,y) \neq (0,0)$, and $h(x,y)=0$ when $(x,y)=(0,0)$. The partial derivative with respect to x is $\frac{2x^5+4x^3y^2+2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$, and the partial derivative with respect to y is $\frac{-3x^2y^2-y^4-2x^4y}{x^2+y^2}$. The partial derivatives are continuous everywhere except at (0,0) as they are rational functions. To prove their continuity at (0,0), we have to take the limit at (0,0). Substitution does not work as the denominator is zero, so I am using squeeze theorem.

For the partial derivative with respect to x, I have $\frac{|2x^5+4x^3y^2+2xy^3|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \le \frac{x^42|x|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} + \frac{4x^2y^2|x|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} + \frac{y^22|xy|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = (\frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2})^22|x| + \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}4|x| + \frac{y^22|xy|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \le 2|x| + 4|x| + \frac{y^22|xy|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$

So as you can see, I am trying to eliminate the denominators by getting a fraction that is less than 1 and can be eliminated using the squeeze theorem. I just cannot figure out what to do with that third term to get rid of the denominator.

For the partial derivative with respect to y, I have $\frac{|-3x^2y^2-y^4-2x^4y|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} \le \frac{3x^2y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} + \frac{y^4}{(x^2+y^2)^2} + \frac{x^4|-2y|}{(x^2+y^2)^2} = \frac{x^2}{x^2+y^2}\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2}3 + (\frac{y^2}{x^2+y^2})^2 +  \frac{x^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}2|y| \le 3 + 1 + 2|y|$

I am trying to do the same thing with the squeeze theorem. Although I get rid of the fractions, that final term is not zero when $(x,y)\rightarrow(0,0)$. I need that term to go to zero for squeeze theorem to work.

What am I doing wrong here? Is there an issue with my calculations, or are these partial derivatives actually just not continuous at (0,0)? If it is the latter, how would I show that?

Comment: You mention that you want to prove that the partial derivatives are continuous at $(0,0)$, but you didn't even compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Wouldn't the partial derivative be undefined at (0,0) due to division by zero? That is why I am trying this squeeze theorem method (and because my professors said to do it).

Comment: It's not easy to prove a false statement... In fact, neither of the two partials $h_x$ and $h_y$ is continuous at the origin. (They are defined at the origin, as you can check using the definition of partial derivative directly, but they don't have a limit as $(x,y) \to (0,0)$, as you can show by approaching the origin from different directions.)

Comment: A function $f$ is **continuous at** $a$ if $f(a)$ *is defined* and $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$. In order to compute the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$ you need to use the [limit definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_derivative#Definition).

Comment: @azif00 So I take the limit of the partial derivative as $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$using the definition? Would that not result in a divide by zero error as well?

Comment: @HansLundmark What exactly do you mean by approaching the origin from different directions? Iterated limits?

Comment: I don’t understand what you mean by taking the limit using the definition. For example, the partial derivative at $(0,0)$ with respect to $x$ is (see the link):
$$
\lim_{t \to 0} \frac{h(t,0)-h(0,0)}{t} = \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{t^4-t^3}{t^3} = \lim_{t \to 0} (t-1) = -1.
$$

Comment: @azif00 That was dumb of me. I see now that you mean taking the partial derivative using the limit definition method. I have $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{h(x,0)-h(0,0)}{x-0}=\lim_{x \to 0}  \frac{x^2-0}{x}=0$. Does this prove that the partial derivative with respect to x is continuous? I also have $\lim_{y \to 0} \frac{h(0,y)-h(0,0)}{y-0}=\lim_{y \to 0}  \frac{-y-0}{y}=-1$. Does this then prove the partial derivative with respect to y is not continuous?

Comment: @ThePevster: Your values of $h(x,0)$ and $h(0,y)$ are incorrect. Anyway, those computation only provide you with the values of $f_x$ and $f_y$ at the point $(0,0)$. In order to see if the function $f_x$ and $f_y$ are continuous at that point you need to check whether that **value** agrees with the **limit** at that point: is $f_x(0,0) = \lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} f_x(x,y)$, and similarly for $f_y$?

Comment: @ThePevster: And by “approaching from different directions”, I definitely don't mean iterated limits, but just the usual way of showing that a multivariable limit doesn't exist. (If you don't know what that refers to, you're not ready for this problem yet; you will need to go back and work on some more basic limit problems first.)

Comment: I searched a little, but I didn't find any good general explanation on this site, but here are some questions just to give you an idea of what I'm referring to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/503738/problems-with-the-existence-of-limits-of-several-variables, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1963052/proving-the-limit-exists-or-not-for-multivariable-functions, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1099267/multivariable-functions-limits-and-paths

Answer (score -2):

There are several other ways you can prove continuity on the function that may be more helpful to your means. The most “Lawful” way to do this is by using L’hopital’s rule:
$$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}\frac{f’(x)}{g’(x)}$$
You could also apply metric space’s properties together with the definition of continuity (hint: in this case you could use the usual metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, $d:\mathbb{R^2 \rightarrow R}$
$$d(x;y)=|p(y_0;y_1)-p(x_0;x_1)|$$
with $p=\nabla(h)$). If you’re willing to get abstract you could even prove it by topological properties!

Nevertheless, if you insist on solving the problem using the sequeeze theorem here are some tips you should have into account:

1-The squeeze theorem needs a pair of additional functions to prove limit values for a given function $p(x)$, just so that in the usual ordering of the real numbers you can get the inequality

$$f(x)\leq p(x)\leq g(x)$$
so when $\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}(f;g)=y$, then $p(x_0)$ must equal $y$. You know $\partial_x(h)\leq |\partial_x(h)|$ (same for $y$) so you need to find a function to give you the lower bound (like $(-1) \cdot|\partial_x(h)|$).

2-Take advantage of the algebra you already did and show convergence for $x$ and $y$ respectively (by treating the other variable as a constant), migth be easier than showing it for $(x;y)$.

3-Don’t lose out of sight the properties of limits. Migth come in handy!

Comment: 1. I am squeezing it using zero as the lower bound. This is why the absolute value of the function was taken. 2. I might try doing that. 3. What properties of limits specifically?

Comment: Oh, i see now. You didn’t mention that you where sequeezing against zero! If you factor out the absolute values of $x$ ($y$) in the expression of $\partial_x(h)$ using $|a\cdot b|=|a|\cdot |b|$, you can use $lim(a+b)=\lim(a)+\lim(b)$ and you will be done.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? I am not exactly sure what to do.

Comment: I’ll exemplify with the $x$ case. We take $p(x)=\partial_x(h)=$ $\frac{2x^5+4x^3y^2+2xy^3}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$. Then $(-1)\cdot|p(x)|\leq p(x)\leq |p(x)|$ (u can’t use zero, since $p(x)$ takes negative values on the interval $(0;1)$) by $|\cdot|$, we have $|p(x)|\leq \frac{|2|\cdot|x^5|+|4y^2|\cdot|x^3|+|2y^3|\cdot|x|}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$ we check that this last expression tends to $0$ as $x\rightarrow 0$ (Use the sum property of limits) and the same happens to its negative, so we can express that $$-|p(x)|\leq0\leq p(x)\leq |p(x)|\leq0$$ for sufficiently small $x$. Hence, $p(0)=0$, by squeeze theorem.